# syncsort convert pd with precision to zdf

Tags: sorting, mainframe, zos, syncsort

I have a need to convert pack decimal(pd) with precision like S9(8)V99 to zone decimal(zd).

> for example:  12345678 should converted like 123456.78

I try to do that by the syntax :

```
outrec fields=(1,4,pd,zdf,edit=(IIIIII.TT))
```

but i got a syntax error on the edit phrase

A Google search shows nothing...

What is the correct syncsort syntax?

Comment: Are you sure the length of your PD field is correct?  Have you tried `OUTREC FIELDS=(1,4,PD,ZDF,EDIT=(IIIIII.TT))` instead of `outrec fields=(1,4,pd,zdf,edit=(IIIIII.TT))`?  If your shop licenses Syncsort then your shop has a manual somewhere.

Comment: OUTREC FIELDS=(1,4,PD,ZDF,EDIT=(IIIIII.TT)) is same  outrec  fields=(1,4,pd,zdf,edit=(IIIIII.TT)) the diff is upper case or lower case.    without convert from pd to zdf the edit=(IIIII.TT) work well (OUTREC FIELDS=(1,4,PD,EDIT=(IIIIII.TT))

Comment: Did you try ```OUTREC FIELDS=(1,4,PD,TO=ZD,EDIT=(IIIIII.TT))```?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it .
outrec fields=(1,4,pd,edit=(IIIIII.TT)) do the work